# how to add a random delay with setTimeout using async or promises

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, settimeout, es6-promise

if i want to print a numbers from 1 to 10 using setTimeout and `delay = Math.random() * 1000`.
Answer would be number from 1 to 10 in random order because of async programming and event loop.

What i want is to print the number in increasing order with same delay above mentioned. This can be done via Promises or Async module. What i mean to say is it should only proceed once number 1 in printed then 2 so on.

Any help would be appreciated.

**NOTE** : Please dont give answers like adding time to a variable and using that variable as a delay.

Comment: So it seems you want to program synchronous behaviour with asynchronous techniques? You should take a look at *promises* and *then*.

Comment: "i want is to print the number in increasing order with same delay above"

So is delay the same every time but randomly generated, or is the delay random every time ?

Comment: @Luke, delay is random everytime

Comment: OK @AbhishekNayyar - I'd throw up an alternative but unless you can explain what's wrong with any of the answers already - it's probably not worth it.

Comment: all answers are working fine and solutions provided here are both sync/promises based as well as vanila javascript based.
So thank to all the contributors...

Answer (score 5):

You could do this like this, using [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

```js
// returns a promise that resolves after the specified number of ms
function delay(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
}

// function that will print the numbers in correct order, with delays
async function print(num) {
    for (let i = 1; i <= num; i++) {

        await delay(Math.random() * 1000); // wait 

        console.log(i); // print number
    }
}

print(10); // actually execute function
```

The function that actually prints the numbers is an `async` function, using a delay based on a promise that resolves after the specified number of milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

es6 fromat

```js
const delay = (m) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, m));

const print = async (num) => { 
     for (let i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
         await delay(Math.random() * 1000);
         console.log(i);
     }  
};
 
print(10);
```

Comment: Also this takes `num` as input but doesn't do anything with it.

Comment: Now the numbers get printed but they don't run in order, which is what OP asked for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a *semi recursive* setTimeout:

```
(function print(value){
   console.log(value);
   if(value<10) setTimeout(print,Math.random()*1000,value+1);
})(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `setInterval` and not `setTimeout` like this

```js
var count = 1;

var printSequence;
function myFunction() { 
    //using setInterval that is referenced by a variable
    printSequence = setInterval(print, Math.random()*1000);
    
}

function print(){
      console.log(count);
      count++;;
      clearInterval(printSequence);
      
      if(count <= 10){
         myFunction();
      }      
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

No need to add extra logic and code here.